# Nhibernate QueryOver Left Outer Joins with conditions

Tags: c#, hibernate, nhibernate, queryover

I found a few resources online but havent really been able to sort this one out

Basically I have a query which has two left outter joins on it

```
var query = session.QueryOver<NewsPost>(() => newsPostAlias)
                    .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => newsPostAlias.PostedBy, () => userAlias)
                    .Left.JoinQueryOver(x => newsPostAlias.Category, () => categoryAlias)
                        .Fetch(x => x.PostedBy).Eager
                        .Fetch(x => x.Category).Eager
                    .Where(x => !x.Deleted);
```

This might be an invalid way of doing it but it appears to not break. Now what I want to do is on the two tables which have left outter joins on i want to make sure the Deleted column in both these tables is false.

However whenever I add that restriction the results only return when the foreign key column in news post is populated, but since this is nullable and why i made it a left outter join this isnt desirable.

Whats the best way of basically making it

```
.Where(x => !x.Deleted && !x.PostedBy.Deleted && !x.Category.Deleted);
```

I've looked into multiqueries, futures and disjunctions, I'm not sure what approach should be taken, obviously I can think of a few ways (bad ways my gut tells me) of doing this but whats the right way? :)

Thanks

EDIT - Accepted Answer Modification

```
return session.QueryOver(() => newsPostAlias)
                    .Fetch(x => x.PostedBy).Eager
                    .Fetch(x => x.Category).Eager
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => newsPostAlias.PostedBy, () => postedByAlias)
                .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => newsPostAlias.Category, () => categoryAlias)
                .Where(() => !newsPostAlias.Deleted)
                .And(() => newsPostAlias.PostedBy == null ||  !postedByAlias.Deleted)
                .And(() => newsPostAlias.Category == null ||  !categoryAlias.Deleted)
                .OrderBy(() => newsPostAlias.PostedDate).Desc
                .Take(10)
                .List();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suppose your query should look like this

```
        Session.QueryOver<NewsPost>()
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.PostedBy, () => userAlias)
            .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Category, () => categoryAlias)
            .Where(x => !x.Deleted)
            .And(x => !userAlias.Deleted)
            .And(x => !categoryAlias.Deleted);
```

Comment: Sorry but by using .And i am ensuring that only rows with PostedBy and Category populated are returned and I couldnt get this to work any other way

Comment: Correction, I can do it this way be doing .Where(() => !newsPostAlias.Deleted)
                    .Where(() => newsPostAlias.PostedBy == null || (userAlias.Id == userId && !userAlias.Deleted))
                    .Where(() => newsPostAlias.Category == null || (categoryAlias.Id == categoryId && !categoryAlias.Deleted))

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work ...

```
var posts = session.QueryOver<NewsPost>()
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.Category, () => category)
    .Left.JoinAlias(x => x.PostedBy, () => user)
    .Where(x => x.Deleted == false)
    .Where(Restrictions
        .Or(
                Restrictions.Where(() => user.Deleted == false), 
                Restrictions.Where<NewsPost>(x => x.PostedBy == null)
        )
    )
    .Where(Restrictions
        .Or(
                Restrictions.Where(() => category.Deleted == false), 
                Restrictions.Where<NewsPost>(x => x.Category == null)
        )
    )
    .List();
```

Was this one of the ways you felt would be bad?? If so, could you please explain why? I do not know enough about optimizing sql, hence am asking ...

Comment: Thank you this way also works lovely with some modification (Couldnt do Restrictions.Where<NewsPost> as it was trying to use that on table from the first part of the restriction, instead used aliases. I have two ways of achieving this now, I'm opting for the above answer modication as I personally prefer using .Where without the restrictions class as it seems cleaner to read to me. Thanks for all the help however, what I was reffering to being a bad way of doing it was by having it all in one query, I could do this with the criteria API and using futures, so thought it might be best to split

Comment: Cool. Though could you please also mention how you would have done it using the criteria api and futures. The advantage of futures is that you can get back multiple result sets in one db roundtrip. But you will still need to do a join, wont you? And isnt it better to let the db do it ...